# Retrieve NGUCID from Rally

Tags: javascript, rally

I am trying to retrieve custom NGUCID field from Rally but when I try to display it I get a value of "undefined". I have tried a few different options such as changing the type to PortfolioItem and Artifact. But it seems to me that the main issue is happening when I am dereferencing the object.

Here's my code:

```
function defectsExample() {
       var displayDefects = function(results) {
         var defectsInfo = "";
         var defect = "";
         var num;
         var swpCounter = 0;
         var storyCounter = 0;

         var re = new RegExp('SWP');

            for (i=0 ; i < results.defects.length ; i++) {
           defect = results.defects[i];
           storyCounter++;

      //     if ((re.test(defect.Name)) == true)    {
           defectsInfo += defect.Name + '<br>' + defect.NGUCID;
            swpCounter++;                         
                                            //       }

         }
         var aDiv = document.getElementById("aDiv");
    //     aDiv.innerHTML = '<strong>Name, State, Severity</strong><br/>';
defectsInfo += 'Number of SWP stories: ' + swpCounter + '<br>';
defectsInfo += 'Total number stories: ' + storyCounter + '<br>';
          aDiv.innerHTML += defectsInfo;
       };

var queryConfig  = {
    /*      type : 'HierarchicalRequirement',
          key : 'defects',
          query: '((Iteration.Name = "Sprint 40") AND ((Project.Name contains "CRM") OR (Project.Name contains "AR")))',
          fetch: true //'Name, AcceptedDate'*/

               type : 'HierarchicalRequirement',
               key : 'defects',
      //         query: '(Iteration.Name = "Sprint 39")',
      //query: '(NGUCID contains "1")',
               fetch: 'Name,FormattedID,Project,NGUCID'

       };

        var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__',
                                                  '__PROJECT_OID__',
                                                   '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
                                                  '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');
       rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, displayDefects);
     }

     rally.addOnLoad(defectsExample);
```

Answer (score 0):

NGUCID is not a standard Rally field, so I assume it is one that you, or your organisation, have added as a Custom Field on the defect artefact type. All custom fields are accessible if the name is prefixed with 'c_'. In your case, it might be that you need to use "defect.c_NGUCID"

If you go to the WSAPI docs (https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) it will show you the field names available to you for the various artefact types.